# Can't do a copy of an object in python 3 with attributes

Tags: python-3.x, oop

I'm using some objects in python with dynamic properties, all with numbers and strings. Also I created a simple method to make a copy of an object. One of the property is a list, but I don't need it to be deep copied. This method seems to work fine, but I found an odd problem. This piece of code shows it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

# class used for the example
class test(object):

    def copy(self):
        retval = test()
        # just create a new, empty object, and populate it with
        # my defined properties
        for element in dir(self):
            if element.startswith("_"):
                continue
            setattr(retval, element, getattr(self, element))
        return retval

test1 = test()
# here I dynamically create an attribute (called "type") in this object
setattr(test1, "type", "A TEST VALUE")
# this print shows "A TEST VALUE", as expected
print(test1.type)
# Let's copy test1 as test2
test2 = test1.copy()
# this print shows also "A TEST VALUE", as expected
print(test2.type)
test2.type = "ANOTHER VALUE"
# this print shows "ANOTHER VALUE", as expected
print(test2.type)
# Let's copy test2 as test3
test3 = test2.copy()
# this print shows "A TEST VALUE", but "ANOTHER VALUE" was expected
print(test3.type)
```

Where is my conceptual error?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your `copy()` method copied the `copy` method (*not* the function from the class) from `test1`, which means that `self` in `test2.copy()` is still `test1`.

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at `dir(test1)`, you'll see that one of the elements is `'copy'`. In other words, you're not just copying the `type` attribute.

**You're copying the `copy` method.**

`test2` gets `test2.copy` set to `test1.copy`, a bound method that will copy `test1`.

Don't use `dir` for this. Look at the instance's `__dict__`, which only contains instance-specific data.